# Logic question- its about propositional logic and it asks for a valuation for statisfiability

Tags: logic, computer-science

I dont understand this question that comes from a past paper, so please any help is appreciated. The part that i dont understand is what does it mean (question 3) that it wants me to consider the situation when it is bright outside and wants the valuation that satisfies b and all of the formulae . I also dont 100% understand number two as im not 100% sure if i did it correctly.

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help 
I hope everyone is having an amazing holiday.[image: question 3 that I am stuck on]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of (2):

Model 1: "John is in his office, the default light setting is activated, the lights are on, and it is not bright outside"

Model 2: "John is not in his office, the default light setting is activated, the lights are on, and it is not bright outside."

Model 3: "John is not in his office, the default light setting is not activated, the lights are on, and it is not bright outside."

Model 4: "John is not in his office, the default light setting is not activated, the lights are not on, and it is not bright outside."

The answer of (3):

The answer is "No". According to above answer to question(2), you can not find any model that satisfies $B$. And syntactically it is because, in the axioms we have "$B\rightarrow \neg L$", so if $B$ is satisfied then $L$ can not be satisfied.

Comment: joonam azizam ghorboonet beram eghho Farshad (Thats all i know in persian lol). Thanks, that was very clear and concise however theres just one part that i still don't understand. In question 3  if we have b satisfied then we have not L but then i got confused because you said that according to the answer for question 2 we  cant find a model where b is satsified but what about model 4.

Comment: In model 4 B is not satisfied, what is your problem? Indeed, in all possible models not only there is no cases in which B and all the formulas are satisfied, but also there is no cases in which B is satisfied.

Comment: Oh okay, that clears up everything now. Thank you very much egho